# HTML ol display issue

Tags: jquery, css

In this case the css display field screws up the behaviour of the list. No numbers are displayed as normal. If I use the css visibility instead it works perfectly.

```
    <ol id="list" > 
        <li style="display:list-item">Mda unu</li>
        <li style="display:none">Mda doi</li>
        <li style="display:list-item">Mda trei</li>
    </ol >
```

But I want to use jQuery to fadeIn() and fadeOut() an element and those functions use the display property not the visibility one and would automatically add a display field.

How can this be solved ?

Comment: have a span of div inside and you apply the display none of div or span?

Comment: your code seems to work.

Comment: By default the li has display: block, why you need to add inline style for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<ol id="list">
  <li><span style="display:block">Mda unu</span>
  </li>
  <li><span style="display:none">Mda doi</span>
  </li>
  <li><span style="display:block">Mda trei</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Use can put the display none to span

Comment: @glad you liked it happy coding